# Correct REST response for "You must POST here before doing anything else"

Tags: rest

We have a login REST service:

```
POST /sessions
```

When the users password has expired the next thing that must happen is that the client application will present a change dialog window and then change the users password via:

```
PUT /users/_ID_/password
```

What is the best way to communicate this intent to the client? At first I wanted to have `POST /sessions` return `See Other (303)`. But this causes a `GET` on `/users/_ID_/password`. I could return a `Multiple Choices (300)` response which the client does not do an automatic get on, or I could return an `OK (200)` and tag in the JSON session object returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look at the [HTTP status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), I'm thinking the following is the best fit:

> **409 Conflict**
>
> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
> state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where
> it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and
> resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict.
> Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the
> user or user agent to fix the problem

There is a conflict with the current state of the session resource because the user needs to change their password before being able to create a session.  You can return the url to the change password screen in this response so that the client knows where to go to fix the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

> At first I wanted to have `POST /sessions` return `See Other (303)`.

This isn't correct.  It would essentially be saying *"Don't `POST` a session here, `POST` a session over there."*  You'd be relying on out-of-band information and hard-coded behaviour to recognise that this isn't the case and you should actually `POST` a new password there instead.

> I could return a `Multiple Choices (300)` response which the client does not do an automatic get on

But you aren't offering multiple choices.

> or I could return an `OK (200)` and tag in the JSON session object returned.

The POST wasn't successful, so you shouldn't respond with `200`.

Are you *really* asking for the "correct REST response" or are you asking how to achieve a particular effect with HTTP?  Because it seems you're looking for loopholes rather than the proper design.

If a request comes in and authorisation fails, then respond with `401 Unauthorized` and a `WWW-Authenticate` header.  Then use a custom authentication scheme that indicates the user needs to change their password.

Comment: Unless my understanding of the situation is not correct, the user hasn't strictly failed authentication.  They got their password correct, however, are now required to change their password before proceeding.

Comment: I'd agree with Aaron, I don't think authentication has failed. But the client needs to do something (which is why I figured 30X was the way to go). Given both the responses have been on the 40X route I accept I'm wrong with that. I'm currently leaning to 409 than 401 but would be grateful for any further input.